# How to get value from Entry widget Tkinter in new window

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have main window in Tkinter, I made another one which opens with pressed button. On that second window I have `Entry` widget where goes email - and I need to get that email and work with it later on, but function `get()` doesn't work. Any ideas please?

shortened code below

```
new_window = Tk()
new_window.minsize(width=200, height=200)
new_window.title("Menu")
nw_entry = Entry(new_window, width=28)
nw_entry.grid(column=0, row=3)

def send():
    if send:
        msg = EmailMessage()
        msg["From"] = my_email
        msg["Subject"] = "Menu"
        msg["To"] = nw_entry.get()
```

it gives me "Unresolved reference" error

I tried different ways of getting it, inside of function, outside - nothing works so far (but I´m just advanced beginner)

Comment: please create a [mre]

Comment: Most probably you have more than one instance of `Tk()`.  Use `Toplevel()` for window other than the main/root window. It is better to provide the full error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

```
def send(subject, body, to):     
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg.set_content(body)
    msg["From"] = my_email
    msg["Subject"] = subject
    msg["To"] = to
```

In your case, add `msg.set_content`.

```
def send():
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['Subject'] = "Menu"
    msg['From'] = my_email
    msg['To'] = nw_entry.get()
    msg.set_content('''Hi, How to get value from Entry widget Tkinter in new window''')

...
```